# Hiding instance declaration from Prelude

Tags: haskell, import

I am playing with Monoids now and wanted to define my instances of `<>` and `mempty` for a list. I wrote this:

```
instance Semigroup [a] where
  (<>) = (++)

instance Monoid [a] where
  mempty = []
```

But got an error:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
     instance Monoid [a] -- Defined at newtype.hs:25:10
     instance Monoid [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

Probably, I need to add this at the beginning of file:

```
import Prelude hiding (???)
```

What should I write in place of "???"?

Comment: You can not hide instance declarations. I do not really see why you want to do that anyway, since for a list, the instances are, exactly defined as you defined these.

Comment: You can however explicitly not import the `Prelude` at all, but then you thus will not import any function of the prelude.

Comment: As @willem-van-onsem explains, you cannot hide implementations. If your goal is pedagogical, a possible viable approach is to define alternative classes Semigroup' and  Monoid', and then implement the instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1060005.4) says:

> Instance declarations cannot be explicitly named on import or export lists. All instances in scope within a module are always exported and **any import brings all instances in from the imported module**. Thus, an instance declaration is in scope if and only if a chain of import declarations leads to the module containing the instance declaration.

It is thus not possible to exclude a certain instance. That being said, here it is not necessary at all to implement your `Semigroup` and `Monoid` for a list, since it is already defined. Indeed if, we inspect the source code, we see for [`Semigroup` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-290):

> ```
> -- | @since 4.9.0.0
> instance Semigroup [a] where
>         (<>) = (++)
>         {-# INLINE (<>) #-}
>
>         stimes = stimesList
> ```

and for [`Monoid` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-297):

> ```
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance Monoid [a] where
>         {-# INLINE mempty #-}
>         mempty  = []
>         {-# INLINE mconcat #-}
>         mconcat xss = [x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]
> ```

So this is already implemented exactly the way you implemented this yourself.

It is usually considered an anti-pattern to implement an instance of a typeclass you did not implement yourself, on a data type you did not implement yourself. This is called an [*orphan instance* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance):

> An orphan instance is a type class instance for class *C* and type *T* which is **neither defined in the module where *C* is defined nor in the module where *T* is defined**.

Usually one wraps a type into another data constructor (with `newtype`) to define different instances for that type for a typeclass.

Comment: I guess it was for pedagogical purpose. I also happened to have the same need: I found that re-implementing some system instances and then comparing the produced code with the system implementation is a very effective way for learning.